# Scheme: recursive zeno function

Tags: recursion, compilation, scheme

The following is a function that sums 1/2^n until it reaches 0 . Can someone tell me whether or not I need an else statement, and how to arrange my parenthesis so there are no compile errors?

```
(define (zeno n)
  (if (= n 0)
      (+ 0)
      (else
        ((+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n )))
         ((zeno(- n 1)))))))
```

Comment: Doesn't this only work because of FP round-off error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have my hat, my tea, and nothing to do for a while at work. You know what time it is.

[dons [code-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) hat]

Firstly, if you had [properly indented](http://faculty.washington.edu/jtenenbg/courses/480/w02/docs/indentation.html) your code, it would read

```
(define (zeno n)
    (if (= n 0)
        (+ 0)
        (else
         ((+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))
          ((zeno (- n 1)))))))
```

---

`if` in Scheme is not like the `if`/`then`/`else` construct of C-like languages. It's actually the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). In other words, `else` makes no sense in this context.

```
(define (zeno n)
    (if (= n 0)
        (+ 0)
        ((+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))
         ((zeno (- n 1)))))))
```

---

You don't need to use `+` to return a number; numbers are self-evaluating.

```
(define (zeno n)
    (if (= n 0)
        0
        ((+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))
         ((zeno (- n 1)))))))
```

---

When you have an expression like `(foo bar baz)`, it usually means

> "Call the function `foo` with arguments `bar` and `baz`"

You can't just add extra parentheses as you please; those change the meaning of the expression. For example, `((foo) (bar baz))` means

> "Call the function `foo` with no arguments, and call its result with the result of calling `bar` with the argument `baz`"

In other words,

```
...
((+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))
 ((zeno (- n 1))))))
```

what you're saying, and almost certainly don't mean, here is

> "Call the function `(+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n)))` with the result of calling the result of calling `zeno` with the argument `(- n 1)` with no arguments."

What you seem to mean is

> "Add `1` divided by `2^n` to the result of calling `zeno` with one less than `n`"

Which means that what you should say is

```
(define (zeno n)
    (if (= n 0)
        0
        (+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n))
           (zeno (- n 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of syntax errors (erroneous parenthesis, mostly), and the `if` form doesn't use `else` - don't get me wrong, it *does* have an "else" part, it's just that you must not explicitly write `else` for it to work. I believe this is what you were aiming for:

```
(define (zeno n)
  (if (= n 0)
      0
      (+ (/ 1 (expt 2 n))
         (zeno (- n 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For a completely different approach, this uses an explicit `do` loop to do the summing. It avoids using `expt` (by design).

```
(define (zeno n)
  (do ((n n (- n 1))
       (sum 0 (+ sum frac))
       (frac 1/2 (/ frac 2)))
      ((zero? n) sum)))
```

It may or may not be more readable when written into its equivalent named `let` form:

```
(define (zeno n)
  (let loop ((n n)
             (sum 0)
             (frac 1/2))
    (if (zero? n)
        sum
        (loop (- n 1) (+ sum frac) (/ frac 2)))))
```

---

For an even more completely different approach, you can use [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) streams:

```
(define zeno
  (let ((frac-stream (stream-iterate (cut / <> 2) 1/2)))
    (lambda (n)
      (stream-fold + 0 (stream-take n frac-stream)))))
```

(The above snippet also requires [SRFI 26](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-26/srfi-26.html) to be loaded, in addition to SRFI 41.)

---

An even even more completely different approach: just use the closed-form solution! (Thanks, WorBlux.)

```
(define (zeno n)
  (- 1 (/ (expt 2 n))))
```

Comment: Can't you also just analytically simplify the function to (let ((base (expt 2 n))) (/ (- base 1) base))  ?

Comment: @WorBlux Well, yes, that's a fair point. :-P (I've edited my answer to incorporate a simpler form of your suggested solution.)